# Why is the form $\omega = \sum dx_i \wedge d\xi_i$ non degenerate?

Tags: symplectic-geometry

Let's consider $M$ to be a smooth manifold with local coordinates $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ on a coordinate chart $U$. Denote by $\partial / \partial x_i$ the dual basis, $dx_j(\partial / \partial x_i)=\delta_{ij}$ and let $\xi_1,\ldots, \xi_n$  be such that $\xi_i: T^*M|_U\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\xi_i(x,\mu)=\mu(\partial / \partial x_i)(x),  (x,\mu) \in T^*_x M.$

In many references they say that  the form
$$\omega = \sum dx_i \wedge d\xi_i$$ is clearly non-degenerate, but I don't know how to show that !

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Verify that the matrix representation of $\omega$ relative to the basis $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi^i}$ is $\pm\begin{pmatrix}0&I_n\\-I_n&0\end{pmatrix}$ ($\pm$ because I can't for the life of me remember the conventions).

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you peek-a-boo and Amitesh Data  for your helpful comments, Now I get the idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick $X=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\partial_{x_i}+b_i\partial_{\xi_i}$ a vector field of $T^*M$, then
\begin{align*}
\omega(X,Y)=0,\ \forall Y&\Longleftrightarrow 0=\omega(X,\partial_{x_j})=-b_j\ \text{and}\ 0=\omega(X,\partial_{\xi_j})=a_j,\ \forall i=1,...,n\\
& \Longleftrightarrow X=0
\end{align*}
$$$$

Comment: Nice idea ! Thank you very much @Anonymous!